# Cisco ASA 5550 rebooted itself, logs cleared

Tags: firewall, cisco, cisco-asa

we had Cisco ASA5550 in Active/standby mode which worked without any issue for over 1 year. Recently, we started having issue where the VPN tunnels would drop to sites and have internet outages. 
We disabled failover and took Standby ASA out of the network.
While the network is operating on one ASA, it rebooted itself without any reason. I am unable find the reason behind logs were erased on reboot. i can confirm there wasn't a power issue as nothing else power cycled.
ASA version: 9.1(5)

Is there any known bug fix? what could case ASA reboot itself?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: As a side note, try to setup a syslog server, so the logs are external to the device. This will stop the logs being cleared in the event of a reboot/failure

Comment: We tried setting up Splunk but wasn't great to use, so stopped it. Any suggestion on syslog server, possibly freeware

Comment: I am looking at setting up Logstash for a central logging server

Comment: As Drifter said, you need a syslog server to capture the logs.  You can also use an snmp server for trap messages.  Googling will return free options for this.  You can't retroactively find root causes when you have no info to work from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at -
http://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-20141008-asa

2015-July-08 UPDATE: Cisco PSIRT is aware of disruption to some Cisco customers with Cisco ASA devices affected by CVE-2014-3383, the Cisco ASA VPN Denial of Service Vulnerability that was disclosed in this Security Advisory. Traffic causing the disruption was isolated to a specific source IPv4 address. Cisco has engaged the provider and owner of that device and determined that the traffic was sent with no malicious intent. Cisco strongly recommends that customers upgrade to a fixed Cisco ASA software release to remediate this issue.